# AttributeConverter not working in EclipseLink, works fine in Hibernate

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, converters

I wanted to try a simple test case with a converter. Unfortunately it doesn't work with payara 5. It works fine with Wildfly 20.0.1. Database is H2.

pom.xml

```
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>fjp</groupId>
    <artifactId>converter</artifactId>
     <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

persistence.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.2"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
>
    <persistence-unit name="primary" transaction-type="JTA">
        <!--jta-data-source>java:/TestDS</jta-data-source-->
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/TestDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>fjp.converter.entity.Employee</class>
        <class>fjp.converter.entity.converter.StatusConverter</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
             <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

DAO :

```
package fjp.converter.dao;    
import java.util.List;   
import fjp.converter.entity.Employee;

public interface EmployeeDAO {
    public Employee find(long i);
    public void create(Employee e);
    public void delete(Employee e);
    public void delete(long i);
    public List<Employee> findByStatus(Employee.Status status);
}
```

DAOImpl

```
package fjp.converter.dao;    
import java.util.List;    
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import fjp.converter.entity.Employee;

@Stateless
public class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public Employee find(long i) {
        return em.find(Employee.class, i);
    }
    @Override
    public void create(Employee e) {
        em.persist(e);
    }
    @Override
    public void delete(long i) {
        var e = this.find(i);
        if(e != null) em.remove(e);
    }
    @Override
    public void delete(Employee e) {
        if(e == null) return;
        delete(e.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public List<Employee> findByStatus(Employee.Status status) {
        return em.createNamedQuery("Employee.findByStatus", Employee.class)
            .setParameter("status", status)
            .getResultList();
    }
}
```

Entity :

```
package fjp.converter.entity;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Convert;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;  
import java.io.Serializable;

@NamedQuery(name="Employee.findByStatus", query="select e from Employee e where e.status=:status")
@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable{

    public enum Status {
        SENIOR("SENIOR"),
        JUNIOR("JUNIOR");
        private String code;
        private Status(String s) {
            this.code = s;
        }
        public String getCode() {
            return this.code;
        }
    }

    @Id
    private long id;
    @Convert(converter = fjp.converter.entity.converter.StatusConverter.class)
    private Status status;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Status getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }
    public void setStatus(Status s) {
        this.status = s;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("id=%d, status=%s", id, status == null ? null : status.getCode());
    }
}
```

Converter :

```
package fjp.converter.entity.converter;    
import javax.persistence.Converter;
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;    
import fjp.converter.entity.Employee.Status;

@Converter
public class StatusConverter implements AttributeConverter<Status, String> {
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Status e) {
        return e == null ? null : e.getCode();
    }
    @Override
    public Status convertToEntityAttribute(String s) {
        if(s == null) return null;
        switch(s) {
            case "SENIOR": return Status.SENIOR;
            case "JUNIOR": return Status.JUNIOR;
            default: return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Servlet

```
package fjp.converter.servlet;    
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;    
import fjp.converter.dao.EmployeeDAO;
import fjp.converter.entity.Employee;
import fjp.converter.entity.Employee.Status;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@WebServlet("/test")
public class Test extends HttpServlet {
    @Inject
    private EmployeeDAO dao;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Employee e = new Employee();
        long id = 1;
        dao.delete(id);
        e.setId(id);
        e.setStatus(Status.SENIOR);
        dao.create(e);

        id = 2;
        dao.delete(id);
        e.setId(id);
        e.setStatus(Status.JUNIOR);
        dao.create(e);

        Status status = Status.SENIOR;
        var list = dao.findByStatus(status);
        for(var o : list) {
            System.out.println(o);
            if(o.getStatus() != status) {
                System.out.println("ERROR !!!!!");
            }
        }
        status = Status.JUNIOR;
        list = dao.findByStatus(status);
        for(var o : list) {
            System.out.println(o);
            if(o.getStatus() != status) {
                System.out.println("ERROR !!!!!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First time you ask the servlet you get the error message :

```
[2021-05-13T19:08:07.512+0200] [Payara 5.2021.3] [PRÉCIS] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session./file:/home/frederic/payara5/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/converter-1.0/WEB-INF/classes/_primary.sql] [tid: _ThreadID=76 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(5)] [timeMillis: 1620925687512] [levelValue: 500] [[
  SELECT ID, STATUS FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE (STATUS = ?)
    bind => [SENIOR]]]

[2021-05-13T19:08:07.514+0200] [Payara 5.2021.3] [INFOS] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=76 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(5)] [timeMillis: 1620925687514] [levelValue: 800] [[
  id=2, status=JUNIOR]]

[2021-05-13T19:08:07.514+0200] [Payara 5.2021.3] [INFOS] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=76 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(5)] [timeMillis: 1620925687514] [levelValue: 800] [[
  ERROR !!!!!]]
```

If you refresh the page : it blows !

```
    Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.payara-p3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Violation dindex unique ou clé primaire: {0}
Unique index or primary key violation: {0}; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (ID, STATUS) VALUES (?, ?) [23505-197]
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you are really seeing - why do you think it is a problem with the converter? What is the data in the database when you issue the query? Try turning on EclipseLink logging to ALL and fully to show all the SQL it issues as well as warnings and problems it might have when deploying and processing the persistence unit.  the problem with the pk violation when retrying suggests this isn't hooked up into transactions correctly, so that the delete statement wasn't executed and committed when the insert is attempted.

Comment: The queries are all correct.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are editing an object after you call persist on it in ways not allowed by the JPA specification. What is happening here is you first create Employee e and set its ID and status (1, SENIOR), and call persist on this instance.

You then change the id and status values on e (2, JUNIOR) and again call persist on that same instance. Instance E though is already persisted, so this is ignored. When you query for status SENIOR, EclipseLink will query and find a row matching (1, SENIOR), but when it goes to the cache to look to see if it already has the data, it'll find your 'e' instance and so just return that. Your application logs an error because you've change the state of e to JUNIOR.

For proof of what is happening - try listing out what is in the database.

The solution is just to create a second Employee instance to represent the (2,JUNIOR) data.

Some differences in JPA providers are that EclipseLink will maintain 1st and 2nd level caches by default. This interferes with this situation because you are modifying objects in ways not allowed within the JPA spec, and EclipseLink remembers the data for longer than if there wasn't a cache. You are not allowed to modify primary keys within JPA.

Comment: You are right. If I create a new Employee instead of reusing it, it works.

However, the Employee in my servlet is detached and I should be able to reuse it, change its id if I want.

I tried to add an equals method based on the id but the bug persists if I reuse the Employee.

What is unacceptable for me is asking for a Status (say JUNIOR) and not getting it ! This is an AssertionError.

Comment: Its not detached, which is the point. Don't use a manage entity from one persistence to another in EclipseLink, as it has hooks to allow it to track changes more efficiently  and difference in caching that will cause behaviour like this. The correct approach is to use a different instance to represent different instance data. You are getting the instance that represents the row in the database, you have just corrupted it so that the data you see isn't what is in the DB anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It works if I add to persistence.xml :

```
<shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
```

So you can reuse the Employe but beware of second level cache.